# "tests" in reviews

Tags: discussion, review-audit

I had a very minor question concerning the "reviews" that we are asked to make (vote to close, to leave open , approve edits ...); more precisely, about the "tests" that are sometimes made.

When you "pass the test", you are congratulated, and everything is fine.

Sometimes, however, you do not "pass", and then you have a message saying that there are "serious problems" with, for example, the question that you did not vote to close. Most of the time this is OK since the "failure" at the test is just because you did not really look at (say) the question, which was a complete nonsense. However, it happened to me 2 or 3 times that I *really* did to not agree for closing a question which was supposed to have "serious problems". And it seemed to me that the only possibility I had was either to quit, or to click on the "I understand" link.

So here's my question: do you think it could be a good idea to add an "I disagree" link close to the "I understand" link?

Of course, if such a link already exists, I just apologize for the question...

Comment: See also my answer to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/stop-look-and-listen/10842#10842

Comment: @BenMillwood Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It happens; the audit system has false positives, partly due to the fact that there is no uniform standard according to which questions get upvoted or closed. So, if your opinion happens to diverge from the majority opinion (precisely, the majority of those who voted on the particular question), you get yelled at. Which isn't pleasant of course, not to mention having to click "I understand".

Meta.SE   has a tag [disputed-review-audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits?sort=votes&pageSize=15)  for this topic. The highest-voted post there is the feature request by hardmath, [Review audits and "I understand" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188780/). It's essentially the same as your proposal. Almost a year later, it remains neither implemented nor declined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link!

Comment: The disputed-review-audit questions can now be found [on the new metaSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits).

Comment: @Goos That's great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have just "failed" for the first time on revising questions for being closed - having passed several other tests. I think that the failure rate could be taken into account in deciding what action to take.

I understand why the question was closed - of course I do - one of those annoying homework ones asking for specific clarification. But one of the criteria I take into account is the amount of effort people have put in to clarifying issues and suggesting ways forward - that is regulars rather than the original poster - what response has it actually attracted? If a number of people have made good quality contributions, I am far less inclined to vote to close the question - in spite of obvious weaknesses it clearly has something of substance about it. Some of these things are closed far too quickly in my view, without giving the original poster time to acknowledge constructive contributions and work with the community to improve the question.

Comment: I take it you are referring to [this review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/198386). IM(NS)HO, it might be the poster child of a "lacking context" question. "Reflexive" has lots of uses in mathematics, and even the tags don't help. One can only _guess_ that someone asking about something other than reflexive _relations_ would add a bit more to the question, but I'm not convinced that this is the best way to judge the suitableness of a question.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Indeed, it lacks context, but the comments give OP a chance to explain that context. Since it was homework and a basic question, it may be that OP would not even understand some of the contexts in which "reflexive" might be used in mathematics, and could be entirely unaware of alternative uses. I thought OP needed a chance to respond to help before closing. Though I understand why it was closed.